# Combine migration in and out data by county

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets, one for `migration inflow` to county `A` from other counties and other for `migration outflow` from county `A` to other counties. In order to combine the two data sets as:

```
County State Inflow Outflow Year
```

The common column between the two datasets are `Origin_Place`, `Origin_StateName` and `Year` in `migration inflow` and `Dest_place`, `Dest_StateName` and `Year` in `migration outflow`.

Part of the problem is that the common columns have unequal number of rows.

How can combine the two into one dataset in such a way that I don't have to hardcode each and every common county name?

My original migration outflow data has 517 observations and migration inflow has 441, thus different number of counties in each dataset.

Dummy data:

```
# People moving out of county A to other counties
Origin_County_Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")

Origin_StateName = c("FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL")

Individuals = c(223, 224, 2333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777)

Dest_place = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")

Dest_StateName = c("BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH")

Year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020)

Outflow_df = data.frame(Origin_County_Name, Origin_StateName,  Individuals, Dest_place, Dest_StateName, Year)

# People moving in county A from other counties
Origin_Place = c("D", "E", "F")

Origin_StateName = c("DD", "EE", "FF")    

Individuals = c(111, 8888, 9999)

Dest_County_Name = c("A", "A", "A")

Dest_StateName = c("FL", "FL", "FL")

Year = c(2019, 2019, 2020)

Inflow_df = data.frame(Origin_Place, Origin_StateName,  Individuals, Dest_County_Name, Dest_StateName, Year)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an outer merge. Use the `all=T` argument for the merge() function

**Answer for first dataset**

```
dfNew <- merge(Outflow_df,Inflow_df,by.x='Dest_place',by.y='Origin_Place',all=TRUE)
dfNew <- dfNew[,c('Dest_place','Individuals.y','Individuals.x')] 
dfNew <- setNames(dfNew,c('County','Inflow','Outflow'))
dfNew[is.na(dfNew)] <- ''
```

**Answer for second dataset**

```
dfNew <- merge(Outflow_df,Inflow_df,by.x=c('Dest_place','Dest_StateName','Year'),
               by.y=c('Origin_Place','Origin_StateName','Year'),
               all=TRUE)
dfNew <- dfNew[,c('Dest_place','Dest_StateName','Individuals.y','Individuals.x','Year')] 
dfNew <- setNames(dfNew,c('County','State','Inflow','Outflow','Year'))
dfNew[is.na(dfNew)] <- ''
dfNew
```

Comment: I am getting an error on line 3 `Error in chr_as_locations():
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column County doesn't exist.`

Comment: @Ed_Gravy sorry about that. I updated my answer

Comment: I slightly modified the datasets by a adding some additional columns, can you kindly modify your answer accordingly? Thank you.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy does my edit work?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after?

```r
names(Outflow_df)[names(Outflow_df) == "Dest_place"] <- "County"
names(Outflow_df)[names(Outflow_df) == "Individuals"] <- "Outflow"
names(Inflow_df)[names(Inflow_df) == "Origin_Place"] <- "County"
names(Inflow_df)[names(Inflow_df) == "Individuals"] <- "Inflow"

merge(Outflow_df[, c("County", "Outflow")], Inflow_df[, c("County", "Inflow")], all = TRUE)
```